# .NET App.Config issues across multiple projects

Tags: c#, .net, settings, app-config

I have a solution that contains two projects.  One project is a Windows Service that contains a few classes for performing various functions.  The other project is a Windows Form Application that is meant for doing various testing and performing task that the service accomplishes on demand.  For instance, the service will do a few various task at a certain time interval, but if you wanted to perform one of those task before the time interval has elapsed, you could load the Windows Forms Application and execute one of the task immediately. The Windows Form Application (from here referred to as the tester) references the Windows Service (from here referred to as Service) project. When the Tester loads, it creates an instance of one of the classes from the Service.  Whenever buttons are pressed to perform the task, it references that instance that was created and calls the various methods of the class. The Service has uses application settings for the configuration, and thus has an app.config.  The configuration settings are accessed using [ProjectName].Properties.Settings.Default.[SettingName].  When the configuration settings for the tester are changed on its own app.config (or exe.config after release), the settings are refreshed without a problem.  If the tester is closed, configuration is modified, and then reopened, the new settings will be populated.  If the Reload method is called on the Settings, the configuration is refreshed without a problem.  The Service performs in the same way.  The configuration settings are can be updated without a problem.

The problem is that if configuration changes need to be made on the service, when the service methods are called from the tester, the configuration does not take the new settings.  Whatever settings the project was built with will be used.  I cannot get the tester to recognize that the app.config/exe.config for the service has changed, and the new configuration should be reloaded and used instead of whatever configuration was used when the project was built in visual studio.  Perhaps it I am not educated enough about this topic, but it seems to me that the app.config is rolled up into the .exe file created by the Service whenever it is built.

I have tried encapsulating the Reload method for the Service and calling it, and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

I have an example project that performs as is described above on a very basic level.  The ideal goal is to be able to modify the exe.config file or files on the fly and have both the Service and the Tester pick them up without any problems.  If you would like to see exactly what I mean from a coding perspective, an example project can be found here: [example solution](http://claychristmas.com/winformstester.zip)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks you for your time.

*Update*

I have managed to find A solution to this, but I am still curious if there is a better way.  By using an app.config that is shared between both projects and using the Configuration Manager instead of App Settings, everything works as it is expected to.  I prefer to use App Settings if at all possible; however it will work to use a shared app.config and the Configuration Manager pointed at that app.config.

Answer (score 0):

One option is having both programs load from the same configuration file:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openexeconfiguration.aspx

Comment: I tried playing around with the ConfigurationManager and the functionality you mentioned above, but it didn't seem to work the way I need it to. I am not using the configuration manager to obtain my configuration values, I am using Application settings, so a using statement to the namespace itself is at the top of the class and configuration options are accessed like so: [ProjectName].Properties.Settings.Default.[SettingName] 

Thank you for your response though.  Do you have any other ideas or is it possible I misunderstood your response?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.  An app.config must be added to the solution as is described above in my update.  Once linked like that, you can add a settings file to the project and add settings/configuration to the project and they will be added to the solutions settings file.  This will move with the build and fix the problem I was having.